# How to deal with csrf security in codeigniter

Tags: api, codeigniter, post, csrf, csrf-protection

I have a project that we should interacting within 2 different application using CI. I use post method for sending request from 1st aplication to 2nd aplication. After I configure the csrf and test using form i got output

```
An Error Was Encountered.The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

I want to know how to handle this?
and i'm using CI v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I believe that you have done proper setup for CSRF. If not please refer Codeigniter CSRF documentation. For this below is link.
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Now, for APIs you need to whitelist that URIs from CSRF.

for this use like this,

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('api/person/add', 'api/person/edit/[0-9]+');
```

Regular expressions are also supported (case-insensitive):

```
    $config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array(
        'api/record/[0-9]+',
        'api/title/[a-z]+'
    );
```

Comment: what is inside that array? is that site url or API url?

Comment: your post url, except `base_url();` that means if your url is `http://example.com/api/person/add` then just put `api/person/add`

Comment: i want to hit example.com/test/index_post from my form in mysite.com/myfrom. i already put 'TRUE' in csrf_token in config example.com and i use <?php $csrf = array('name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash());?> <input type="hidden" name="<?=$csrf['name'];?>" value="<?=$csrf['hash'];?>"> to generate token from my form. but the same error still showed. how i fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('test/index_post', 'test/index');` in config.php

Comment: sorry before, im using CI 2 and i just know that in CI version 2 doesnt have csrf_exclude_uris functions

Comment: Hi, does this mean that if I have a ton of rest post requests, I have to list all of them? Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: No, If you are using CI for a ton of rest post than CSRF is not recommended, this feature is for form submission and other purposes in CI, instead of this use Rest API structure with Authentication Token or JWT for security purpose.